# Sql query correct syntax

Tags: sql

I'm trying to return in a reporting service, the count of ID and NUM, that have the USERID AND CREATION_DATE entered by the user.
My aim is to get one row as a result, containing both counts. I'm getting the count correct however I'm being displayed with several rows as 
a return. (which are the rows that have the parameters specified by the user). How can I get only one row containing only the fields COUNTID and COUNTNUM.
I'm using Microsoft sql server.

```
SELECT

     (SELECT COUNT(ID)
        FROM   PART
        WHERE  USERID = $P{userId} and CREATION_DATE = $P{creationDate}) as COUNTID ,
  (SELECT COUNT(NUM)
        FROM   IDENTITY
        WHERE  USERID = $P{userId}  and CREATION_DATE = $P{creationDate}) as COUNTNUM 
FROM
      PART,
      IDENTITY
```

Comment: Try removing the `FROM` clause if your backend database is SQL Server or using `FROM DUAL` instead if it's Oracle.

Comment: Could you specify which DB engine you use?

Comment: Can either or both COUNTs ever be zero? Some of the answers offered won't work if this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to return one row, and each of your subqueries is returning the "count" you want, you could just remove the `FROM` clause from the outer query. Something like this:

```
  SELECT ( SELECT COUNT(p.ID)
             FROM PART p
            WHERE p.USERID        = $P{userId}
              AND p.CREATION_DATE = $P{creationDate}
         ) AS COUNTID
       , ( SELECT COUNT(i.NUM)
             FROM IDENTITY i
            WHERE i.USERID        = $P{userId}
              AND i.CREATION_DATE = $P{creationDate}
         ) AS COUNTNUM
```

Personally, I'd write the query a little differently. I'd use the subqueries as inline views cross joined in the FROM clause, with each of the inline views returning a single row. Like this:

```
  SELECT cp.countid
       , ci.countnum
    FROM ( SELECT COUNT(p.ID) AS countid
             FROM PART p
            WHERE p.USERID        = $P{userId}
              AND p.CREATION_DATE = $P{creationDate}
         ) cp
   CROSS
    JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(i.NUM) AS countnum
             FROM IDENTITY i
            WHERE i.USERID        = $P{userId}
              AND i.CREATION_DATE = $P{creationDate}
         ) ci
```

Comment: Note that the subqueries are guaranteed to return a row. Even when no rows that satisfy the predicates, the COUNT() aggregate will still return 0.Both of the queries in this answer will return "zero" counts.

Answer (score 0):

Use a join and a Group By -- like this:

```
SELECT P.USERID, P.CREATION_DATE, COUNT(P.ID) AS COUNTID, COUNT(I.NUM) AS COUNTNUM
FROM PART P
JOIN IDENTITY I ON P.USERID = I.USERID AND P.CREATION_DATE = I.CREATION_DATE
WHERE P.USERID = $P{userId}  and P.CREATION_DATE = $P{creationDate}
GROUP BY P.USERID, P.CREATION_DATE
```

As a side bonus if you take out the `WHERE` you can see the results for all users and all dates.

Note, if not all users and dates are in the PART table or Identity table do this:

```
SELECT B.USERID, B.CREATION_DATE, COUNT(P.ID) AS COUNTID, COUNT(I.NUM) AS COUNTNUM
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT USERID, CREATEION_DATE FROM PART
    UNION 
   SELECT DISTINCT USERID, CREATEION_DATE FROM IDENTITY
) AS B
LEFT JOIN PART P ON B.USERID = P.USERID AND B.CREATION_DATE = P.CREATION_DATE
LEFT JOIN IDENTITY I ON B.USERID = I.USERID AND B.CREATION_DATE = I.CREATION_DATE
WHERE B.USERID = $P{userId}  and B.CREATION_DATE = $P{creationDate}
GROUP BY B.USERID, B.CREATION_DATE
```

> NOTE: This second query is **much** more correct, but might not be needed depending on your data.  *Since you don't tell us anything about your data or data model it is hard for me to know if the first query will work.*

Comment: dear when it comes to your second solution, I'm getting one row. however for the count instead of getting 1,7 which is my correct solution...I'm getting 14 for each count

Comment: @user243837 - try changing `UNION ALL` to `UNION`.  If that does not work I will have to see your sample data to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: by doing that now the count is COUNTID 7 COUNTNUM 7.. Countnum is correct, however countid should be 1..

Comment: NOTE: The "counts" returned by the queries in this answer are significantly *different* from the "counts" returned by the OP subqueries in the question.

Comment: @user243837 -- are you sure you used left joins -- what you are describing sounds like cross joins.